# Setting value of FormControl does not trigger valueChanges

Tags: html, angular, forms, rxjs, angular-material

I have an Angular Material Autocomplete and I am trying to trigger the valueChanges subscription by setting a value in ngAfterViewInit. But nothing happens and I dont know why. I also checked similar questions and the answers didnt help me out so far.

This is the relevant code:

```
options$?: Observable<GroupOption[]>;
  /** interne Liste der Optionen zum Filtern, Prüfen etc. von Items */
  private options: GroupOption[] = [];
  private emptyOption: OptGroupItem = {
    group: '',
    name: '',
    id: '',
  };

  control = new FormControl('');

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.options$ = this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this.createGroupOptions(value)),
      tap(value => console.log(value))
    );

    this.options$.subscribe(res => {
      console.log("options");
      console.log(res);
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('what is inside field?');
    console.log(this.control.value);
    this.control.setValue(this.emptyOption);
  }
```

And my html:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
  <ng-container>
    <input
      type="text"
      matInput
      [formControl]="control"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    />

    <mat-autocomplete
      #auto="matAutocomplete"
      (optionSelected)="onDropdownChange($event)"
      [displayWith]="displayName"
    >
      <mat-optgroup
        *ngFor="let option of options$ | async"
        [label]="option.group"
      >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of option.items" [value]="item">
          {{ item.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-optgroup>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </ng-container>
</mat-form-field>
```

Maybe you know whats going on? Thanks for every help!

Comment: You should start by creating a form with the formBuilder. A formControl doesnt make sense without a form.

Comment: @ukn there is a form in the parent component, they are connected

Comment: They wont be connected unless you passed the formcontrol initialised from the parent as an input of the form itself to the filed later on. The reason why Im telling you this is everything seems to be disconnected since valueChanges should be working

Comment: I agree with you usually about this matter. But in this case the form is a directive and not simply used between parent and child. they should be connected